# Assign value from one array to values from another

Tags: php

I have three arrays:

```
$objective = isset($_POST['objective'])?$_POST['objective']:'';
$key_result = isset($_POST['key_result'])?$_POST['key_result']:'';
$doit = isset($_POST['doit'])?$_POST['doit']:'';

Array ( [0] => Objective 1 [1] => Objective 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => key_result 1 1 [1] => key_result 1 2 [2] => key_result 1 3 [3] => key_result 2 1 [4] => key_result 2 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => doit [1] => doit 2 )
```

Is there any way I can get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                        [0] => Objective 1 
                        [1] => key_result 1 1 
                        [2] => key_result 1 2 
                        [3] => key_result 1 3 
                        [4] => doit
                     ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                        [0] => Objective 2 
                        [1] => key_result 2 1 
                        [2] => key_result 2 2 
                        [3] => doit 2
                     ) 
)
```

What i tried:

```
foreach( $objective as $obj => $ob ) 
{
    $array_test4[] = array($ob, $key_result[$obj], $doit[$obj]);

    $test4 = implode('<>',array_map(function ($innerArray) {
    return implode("|",$innerArray);
    },$array_test4));
}print_r($array_test4);
```

But I dont get what i want. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are the `key_result` parameters supposed to match up with the `objective` and `doit` parameters?

Comment: How does it know that the first 3 elements of `$key_result` should be in the first array, and the next 2 should be in the second array?

Comment: @barmar i dont know, any ideas how can I let system know? Because amount of `$key_result` depends on user's input. so it can be more than 3. Is there any way I can assign `$key_result` parameters to objective?

Comment: Maybe you should make `key_result` a 2-dimensional array, so it matches up with `objective` and `doit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solved my problem:
Before submitting the form I added hidden inputs where I need to divide it:

```
<input type='hidden' name="objective[]" value=",">
<input type='hidden' name="objective[]" value="<|>">
```

Then I put all data in one array:

```
$objective = isset($_POST['objective'])?$_POST['objective']:'';
```

After I just removed and replaced unnecessary characters:

```
$objective = isset($_POST['objective'])?$_POST['objective']:'';
$objective_implode = implode("|", $objective);
$objective_replace = str_replace("|<|>|","<>",$objective_implode);
$objective_replace_end = str_replace("|<|>","",$objective_replace);
$objective_replace_comma = str_replace("|,|",",",$objective_replace_end);
```

In the end I got what I wanted. I dont actually need 2d array any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach( $objective as $obj => $ob ) 
{
    $array = array($ob);
    $pattern = "/^key_result ".($obj + 1)."/";
    $value = (preg_grep($pattern, ($key_result)));
    $array = array_merge($array, $value);    
    $array = array_merge($array, array($doit[$obj]));
    $array_test4[] = $array;
}
```